# Structure and pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, text-files

I am trying to read line by line from a text file and put the values in a structure.

My input is:

> name1 name2 01.01.2015 . .

The code I have written below is working but all the arrays have the same values (of the last line of file). I thought it is because my elements are only coping the pointer? But still couldn't find a solution for this? Maybe someone have a quick look to help.

```
int main() {

struct table {  
    char *nachname; 
    char *vorname; 
    char *tag; 
    char *monat; 
    char *jahr;
    int q;
};

int i;
char *file = "OefbTeam1neu.dat", *token;
int lines = getLineCount(file);
FILE *readtxt = fopen(file, "r");
struct table team[lines];

//char vn[lines][100], nn[lines][100], geb[lines][100]; // array of characters in array of strings

rewind(readtxt);

for(i=0 ; i < lines ; i++) {

    char vn[100], nn[100], geb[100];
    char *t , *m , *y;
    int iread = fscanf(readtxt, "%s %s %s \n", nn, vn, geb); 

    token = strtok(geb, ".");

    while( token != NULL ) {
        t = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, ".");
        m = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, ".");
        y = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }

    team[i].nachname = nn;
    team[i].vorname = vn;
    team[i].tag = t;
    team[i].monat = m;
    team[i].jahr = y;
    team[i].q = i;

    //printf("%s %s %s %s %s \n", team[i].nachname, team[i].vorname, team[i].tag, team[i].monat, team[i].jahr);
}
fclose(readtxt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the same arrays (vn, nn, geb) for each iteration, so the fields in table structure all have the same address, so they all point to the same string.  With each iteration, you reading the next line in the file into these buffers, so the contents of these arrays have the last line read.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same temporary variable for all `team[]` elements.. so all `team[]` elements points to the last item.

You need have independent memory for each `team[]`item, for example in your struct:

```
struct table {  
    char nachname[100]; 
    char vorname[100]; 
    char tag[100]; 
    char monat[100]; 
    char jahr[100];
    int q;
};
```

And copy temporary strings buffers with strcpy..

```
strcpy( team[i].nachname, nn );
strcpy( team[i].vorname, vn );
strcpy( team[i].tag, t );
strcpy( team[i].monat, m );
strcpy( team[i].jahr, y );
```

Bye!